# Convert hour with AM/PM to numeric hour in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a dataset in SAS which has character values in the form "8AM", "11AM", "5PM", etc.. My question is how can I convert these to a numeric value, preferably in the 24 hour format?

The closest I've gotten is 1) `newvar = input(oldvar, 1.);` or 2) `newvar = input(oldvar, 2.);`, but this doesn't quite work for each observation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a dedicated informat for this, so you can't use the `INPUT` function without a bit of preprocessing first. The `TIMEw.` informat can be used on values that look like this:

```
8:00 PM
```

So, we just need a couple of lines of code (could condense into one, but better for readability):

```
pm     =tranwrd(oldvar,'P',':00 P');
ampm   =tranwrd(pm,'A',':00 A');
newvar =input(ampm,time8.);
```

We use the `TRANWRD` function to replace incidences of 'A', and 'P' with ':00 A' and ':00 P' respectively, so that they fit the informat and can be read in as time values.

Use a `FORMAT` statement in your data-step to display the values as 24-hour:

```
FORMAT newvar TIME9.;
```

**Extra reading**

TRANWRD function -  http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000215027.htm

TIME format documentation - http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000197928.htm